# Oracle APEX Datepicker

Tags: oracle, datepicker, oracle-apex

We updated APEX to version 21.2.3

We also updated the theme.

In this new version there was a change in the datepicker component.

The problem is that we need to create a mask that inserts the slash that separates the day of the month and the month of the year.

For example: the user wants to enter the date 10/15/2010. When the user types 15 (which is the day), the system inserts the slash "/", that is, the user only inserts the numbers and the system inserts the two slashes.

Before we used javascript to do this, but now it's giving an error and we don't know how to solve it.

Any idea?

My javascript ..

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function formatar_mascara(src,mascara){
    var campo = src.value.length;
    var saida = mascara.substring(0,1);
    var texto = mascara.substring(campo);
    if(texto.substring(0,1) != saida) {
          src.value+=texto.substring(0,1);
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

and the error is ...

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
at formatar_mascara (f:25:27)
at Object.javascriptFunction (f:166:269)
at Object.da.doAction (desktop_all.min.js:22:5467)
at Object.da.doActions (desktop_all.min.js:22:3909)
at HTMLElement. (desktop_all.min.js:22:2575)
at Function.each (desktop_all.min.js:2:3003)
at S.fn.init.each (desktop_all.min.js:2:1481)
at Object.da.actions (desktop_all.min.js:22:2401)
at HTMLElement. (desktop_all.min.js:22:626)
at HTMLElement.dispatch (desktop_all.min.js:2:43064)

Comment: No idea. Though, you didn't post Javascript code you used nor error you got. How is anyone supposed to guess what went wrong?

Comment: Good idea, thanks